# Nonzero for integers

Tags: python, numpy, random, bitstring

My problem is as follows. I am generating a random bitstring of size n, and need to iterate over the indices for which the random bit is 1. For example, if my random bitstring ends up being 00101, I want to retrieve [2, 4] (on which I will iterate over). The goal is to do so in the fastest way possible with Python/NumPy.

One of the fast methods is to use NumPy and do

```
bitstring = np.random.randint(2, size=(n,))
l = np.nonzero(bitstring)[0]
```

The advantage with `np.non_zero` is that it finds indices of bits set to 1 much faster than if one iterates (with a for loop) over each bit and checks if it is set to 1.

Now, NumPy can generate a random bitstring faster via `np.random.bit_generator.randbits(n)`. The problem is that it returns it as an integer, on which I cannot use `np.nonzero` anymore. I saw that for integers one can get the count of bits set to 1 in an integer x by using `x.bit_count()`, however there is no function to get the indices where bits are set to 1. So currently, I have to resort to a slow `for` loop, hence losing the initial speedup given by `np.random.bit_generator.randbits(n)`.

How would you do something similar to (and as fast as) `np.non_zero`, but on integers instead?

Thank you in advance for your suggestions!

Comment: Whats wrong with your current solution?

Comment: I need it to be faster because this is used in a Monte-Carlo algorithm

Comment: I meant what is wrong with your fast numpy method example, not what is wrong with the for loop example

Comment: do you care about `bitstring` or do you only want the indicies?

Comment: I would only need the indices. The random bit string is used to mimick getting a random combination when given n objects

Comment: might be worth moving your update into an answer, https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.  if you really care about performance of just this one thing, you might use cython or numba

Comment: I'm surprised no one has mentioned [`numpy.unpackbits`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unpackbits.html). For large `n`, generating random bits as a packed array of uint8s and unpacking sounds to me like it'd be the fastest option.

Comment: @user2357112 looks useful, but am struggling to turn it into something fast! `np.nonzero(np.unpackbits(np.random.randint(256, size=(n + 7) // 8, dtype=np.ubyte))[:n])[0]` is basically the same performance as `func1`

Answer (score 1):

A minor optimisation to your code would be to use the new style random interface and generate `bool`s rather than 64bit integers

```
rng = np.random.default_rng()

def original(n):
    bitstring = rng.integers(2, size=n, dtype=bool)
    return np.nonzero(bitstring)[0]
```

this causes it to take ~24 µs on my laptop, tested `n` upto 128.

I've previously noticed that getting a Numpy to generate a [permutation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.Generator.permutation.html) is particularly fast, hence my comment above.  Leading to:

```
def perm(n):
    a = rng.permutation(n)
    return a[:rng.binomial(n, 0.5)]
```

which takes between ~7 µs and ~10 µs depending on `n`.  It also returns the indicies out of order, not sure if that's an issue for you.  If your `n` isn't changing much, you could also swap to using `rng.shuffle` on an pre-allocated array, something like:

```
n = 32
a = np.arange(n)

def shuffle():
    rng.shuffle(a)
    return a[:rng.binomial(n, 0.5)]
```

which saves a couple of microseconds.

Comment: not sure how obvious it is that my answer targets the same distribution, could add an explanation if that would help!

Comment: It does make sense! In fact I would previously solve the problem the way you do, that is, first choose the number `k` of elements in the combination that will be output, which is done using a binomial with probability 1/2. Then, select `k` elements uniformly at random from the `n` elements available. Thinking about it recently, it seemed faster (conceptually) to just generate random bits, rather than do the two-step process . In any case, I will benchmark it with the other examples  I have to see the difference, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

After some interesting proposals, I decided to do some benchmarking to understand how the running times grow as a function of `n`. The functions tested are the following:

```py
def func1(n):
    bit_array = np.random.randint(2, size=n)
    return np.nonzero(bit_array)[0]

def func2(n):
    bit_int = np.random.bit_generator.randbits(n)
    a = np.zeros(bit_int.bit_count())
    i = 0
    for j in range(n):
        if 1 & (bit_int >> j):
            a[i] = j
            i += 1
    return a

def func3(n):
    bit_string = format(np.random.bit_generator.randbits(n), f'0{n}b')
    bit_array = np.array(list(bit_string), dtype=int)
    return np.nonzero(bit_array)[0]

def func4(n):
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    a = rng.permutation(n)
    return a[:rng.binomial(n, 0.5)]

def func5(n):
    a = np.arange(n)
    rng.shuffle(a)
    return a[:rng.binomial(n, 0.5)]
```

I used timeit to do the benchmark, looping 1000 over a statement each time and averaging over 10 runs. The value of `n` ranges from 2 to 65536, growing as powers of 2. The average running time is plotted and error bars correspondond to the standard deviation.

[image: Error plot with average running times]

For solutions generating a bitstring, the simple `func1` actually performs best among them whenever `n` is large enough (`n>32`). We can see that for low values of `n` (`n`< 16), using the `randbits` solution with the `for` loop (`func2`) is fastest, because the loop is not costly yet. However as `n` becomes larger, this becomes the worst solution, because all the time is spent in the `for` loop. This is why having a `nonzero` for integers would bring the best of both world and hopefully give a faster solution. We can observe that `func3`, which does a conversion in order to use `nonzero` after using `randbits` spends too long doing the conversion.

For implementations which exploit the binomial distribution (see Sam Mason's answer), we see that the use of `shuffle` (`func5`) instead of `permutation` (`func4`) can reduce the time by a bit, but overall they have similar performance.

Considering all values of `n` (that were tested), the solution given by Sam Mason which employs a binomial distribution together with shuffling (`func5`) is so far the most performant in terms of running time. Let's see if this can be improved!

Comment: `numpy.random.bit_generator.randbits` isn't part of the NumPy public API. (The public API is defined by what's documented, not by the presence or absence of leading underscores.) It's not actually NumPy functionality at all; it's just `secrets.randbits` from the standard library. You can see that the NumPy [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.23.5/numpy/random/bit_generator.pyx#L38) just does `from secrets import randbits`, because that code needs to use `secrets.randbits` internally.

Comment: If you want to use it, just import `secrets.randbits` yourself - or if you don't need cryptographic-quality random bits, just use `random.getrandbits` from the standard `random` module.

Comment: @user2357112 I noticed and tidied that up when benchmarking against my cython code

Answer (score 1):

I had a play with Cython to see how much difference it would make.  I ended up with quite a lot of code and only ~5x better runtime performance:

```
from cpython.pycapsule cimport PyCapsule_IsValid, PyCapsule_GetPointer

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython

from numpy.random cimport bitgen_t

np.import_array()

DTYPE = np.uint32
ctypedef np.uint32_t DTYPE_t

cdef extern int __builtin_popcountl(unsigned long) nogil
cdef extern int __builtin_ffsl(unsigned long) nogil

cdef const char *bgen_capsule_name = "BitGenerator"

@cython.boundscheck(False)  # Deactivate bounds checking
@cython.wraparound(False)   # Deactivate negative indexing.
cdef size_t generate_bits(object bitgen, np.uint64_t *state, Py_ssize_t state_len, np.uint64_t last_mask):
    cdef Py_ssize_t i
    cdef size_t nset
    cdef bitgen_t *rng

    capsule = bitgen.capsule
    if not PyCapsule_IsValid(capsule, bgen_capsule_name):
        raise ValueError("Expecting Numpy BitGenerator Capsule")
    rng = <bitgen_t *> PyCapsule_GetPointer(capsule, bgen_capsule_name)

    with bitgen.lock:
        nset = 0
        for i in range(state_len-1):
            state[i] = rng.next_uint64(rng.state)
            nset += __builtin_popcountl(state[i])

        i = state_len-1
        state[i] = rng.next_uint64(rng.state) & last_mask
        nset += __builtin_popcountl(state[i])
    
    return nset

cdef size_t write_setbits(DTYPE_t *result, DTYPE_t off, np.uint64_t state) nogil:
    cdef size_t j
    cdef int k
    j = 0
    while state:
        # find first set bit returns zero when nothing is set
        k = __builtin_ffsl(state) - 1
        # clear out bit k
        state &= ~(1ul<<k)
        # record in output
        result[j] = off + k
        j += 1
    return j

@cython.boundscheck(False)  # Deactivate bounds checking
@cython.wraparound(False)   # Deactivate negative indexing.
def rint(bitgen, unsigned int n):
    cdef Py_ssize_t i, j, nset
    cdef np.uint64_t[::1] state
    cdef DTYPE_t[::1] result

    state = np.empty((n + 63) // 64, dtype=np.uint64)

    nset = generate_bits(bitgen, &state[0], len(state), (1ul << (n & 63)) - 1)

    pyresult = np.empty(nset, dtype=DTYPE)
    result = pyresult

    j = 0
    for i in range(len(state)):
        j += write_setbits(&result[j], i * 64, state[i])

    return pyresult
```

The above code is easy to use via the [Cython Jupyter extension](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/quickstart/build.html#using-the-jupyter-notebook).

Comparing this to slightly tidied up versions of the OP's code can be done via:

```
import random
import timeit

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

bitgen = np.random.PCG64()

def func1(n):
    # bool type is a bit faster
    bit_array = np.random.randint(2, size=n, dtype=bool)
    return np.nonzero(bit_array)[0]

def func2(n):
    # OPs variant ends up using a CSPRNG which is slower
    bit_int = random.getrandbits(n)
    # this is much easier than using numpy arrays
    return [i for i in range(n) if 1 & (bit_int >> i)]

def func3(n):
    bit_string = format(random.getrandbits(n), f'0{n}b')
    bit_array = np.array(list(bit_string), dtype='int8')
    return np.nonzero(bit_array)[0]

def func4(n):
    # shuffle variant is mostly the same
    # plot already busy enough
    a = np.random.permutation(n)
    return a[:np.random.binomial(n, 0.5)]

def func_cython(n):
    return rint(bitgen, n)

result = {}
niter = [2**i for i in range(1, 17)]
for name in 'func1 func2 func3 func4 func_cython'.split():
    result[name] = res = []
    for n in niter:
        t = timeit.Timer(f"fn({n})", f"fn = {name}", globals=globals())
        nit, dt = t.autorange()
        res.append(dt / nit)

plt.loglog()
for name, times in result.items():
    plt.plot(niter, np.array(times) * 1000, '.-', label=name)
plt.legend()
```

Which might produce output like:

[image: tidied up matplotlib output]

Note that in order to reduce variance it's helpful to turn off CPU frequency scaling and turn off turbo modes.  The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/CPU_frequency_scaling#Scaling_governors) has useful info on how to do this under Linux.

Comment: Thanks for the new benchmark Sam! It seems (given the plots) the best we could hope for would be a curve looking like the purple one but starting at 10^{-3} (like the orange one). I wonder whether that would be achievable by mixing `getrandbits` with Cython.

Comment: @adrien_vdb yup, but even getting this far was far more code than I was hoping for.  I keep getting reminded how bad the constant costs are with numpy, i.e. there's a fixed cost for each numpy operation and this significantly impacts performance when the code isn't working with large arrays.  sticking with vanilla Python is an order of magnitude faster for scalar operations

Answer (score 0):

you could convert the number you get with randbits(n) to a numpy.ndarray.
depending on the size of n the compute time of the conversion should be faster than the loop.

```
n = 10
l = np.random.bit_generator.randbits(n) # gives you the int 616
l_string = f'{l:0{n}b}' # gives you a string representation of the int in length n 1001101000
l_nparray = np.array(list(l_string), dtype=int) # gives you the numpy.ndarray like np.random.randint [1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0]
```